# can symlink to another drive by read by php?

Tags: php, windows

OS: Windows 7, PHP:5.3.2
When I make symlink to the local folder, everything works OK and I can get folder contents.

```
mklink /D linked_dir c:\real_dir\
```

Both PHP and cmd.exe dir show me files in linked_dir.
But, when I make symlink to the shared drive

```
mklink /D linked_dir x:\php\
```

cmd.exe dir shows the files, and php says:

```
[function.opendir]: failed to open dir. No such file or directory in ...
```

Does anyone know how to overcome this issue? is_link, readlink etc... also doesn't provide anything, as if PHP cannot understand directory links at all. 
I really need to read by PHP shared folder contents linked to my local working directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These might be bugs. See the [Changlog for PHP 5.3.4](http://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.3.4)

- Fixed symbolic resolution support when the target is a DFS share.
- Improved support for is_link and related functions on Windows.
- Implemented symbolic links support for open_basedir checks.
- [#51804 SplFileInfo::getLinkTarget() Fails.](http://bugs.php.net/51804)

So, if possible, upgrade to PHP 5.3.4 and see if that fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Problem here might be that the symlink directory is not available or accessible by the www user (the user under which your server runs). Check the permissions of the server acount.